# Issue with displaying icons in div, alignment

Tags: css, html

I need help with below design, what is the best way to align items?
What I would like to achieve is to have all the icons displayed in equal proportions, same padding, margin, etc

When the page collapses to mobile view, two icons should be on top, and two below. That is why I have two medium-up divs.

[image: Icos Picture]

```html
<div  class="grid grid--no-gutters">
          <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half">
   <span class="safe-ico margin-ico" style="float:left; text-align:center;">
               <picture>
               
                <img src="{{'safe_buy_pink.png' |  file_img_url}}" style="width:auto;" alt="example"/>
              </picture> 
              <p class="ico-product">asdsad<br/>asdsad</p>
            </span>
            
            <span class="safe-ico" style="text-align:center;">
     <picture>
            
                <img src="{{'delivery_pink.png' |  file_img_url}}" style="width:auto;" alt="example"/>
              </picture>  
              <p class="ico-product">Brezplačna<br/>% asdsadsa</p>
            </span>
            
          </div>
          <div class="grid__item medium-up--one-half" >
   <span class="safe-ico margin-ico" style="float:left; text-align:center;">
              <picture>
 
                <img src="{{'returns_pink.png' |  file_img_url}}" style="width:auto;" alt="example"/>
              </picture>  
              <p class="ico-product">asdsad<br/>asdsadsa</p>
            </span>
            
            <span class="safe-ico" style="text-align:center;">            
              <picture>
              
                <img src="{{'payments_pink.png' |  file_img_url}}" style="width:auto;" alt="example"/>
              </picture>            
              <p class="ico-product">Različne<br/>moasdsadžnosti asdsad</p>
            </span>            
          </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: Use Flexbox https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score -1):

You can use the following in the style

```
display :inline-block;
```